# How to stop HTML5 range input at a number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html-input

I am using angularjs to stop range slider at 75 but its not a good way. Can some body guide me how to do it? [EDIT to clarify after max=75 answer] Remember I do want to show total 100 or maximum scale but still want to limit to 75 percent or at 75.

```
<html ng-app="root">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="index">{{message}}
        <input type=range ng-model="data.sl" id=sl />
        <input type=text ng-model="data.sl" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="angular.js"></script>

angular.module('root', [])
.controller("index", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello World!";
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.sl = 12;
    $scope.$watch('data.sl',function(nv,ov){
        if(nv==ov)return;

        if(nv >= 75){
            document.getElementById("sl").stepDown(10);
            console.log("going up");
        }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: `<input type="range" max="100">`

Comment: ^there you go thats all

Comment: No I do want to show the maximum value of 100 but still stop at 75!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `max` attribute to limit the maximum value of the range input. Like so:

```
<input type="range" value="0" max="75">
```

For more information you can use check out MDN's documentation [about the input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).

Comment: No I do want to show the maximum value of 100 but still stop at 75! I am not so much newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I go:

```
    $scope.$watch('data.sl',function(nv,ov){
    if(nv==ov)return;

    if(nv >= 75){
        //document.getElementById("sl").stepDown(10);
        $scope.data.sl=75;
        console.log("going up");
    }
    if(nv <= 25){
        //document.getElementById("sl").stepDown(10);
        $scope.data.sl=25;
        console.log("going down");
    }
});
```